# Can't insert link into mysql database

Tags: php, sql, hyperlink, insert

Here is a part of my insert code that troubles me:

```
$recepient="test@email.com";
$text="Please track: http://wwwapps.ups.com/WebTracking/processInputRequest?HTMLVersion=5.0&loc=en_US&Requester=UPSHome&tracknum=123456789&AgreeToTermsAndConditions=yes&ignore=&track.x=24&track.y=9";
$date="2013-05-03 08:12:20"; 
$through="mail";
$status=1;
$q = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`recepient`,`text`,`date`,`through`,`status`) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($to)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($text)."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".mysql_real_escape_string($rowuser['through'])."','".intval($status)."')";
try {$db->query($q);} catch(PDOException $ex) {echp" Error: ".$ex.);}
```

If I remove the link from the $text variable I can see the data added to the database. But in the way I need it to add with the link - the script stops not reporting any errors.

Comment: Sorry for the variables mess: recepient=to, but the idea is only about $text variable here.

Comment: can you provide the function `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: @David Starkey - [From php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Comment: as far as I know, PDO doesn't require `mysql_real_escape_string`, so try without and rather use parameters and prepared statements.

Comment: @Vasiliy - Insert standard comment here about 'mysql_ is getting deprecated, use mysqli_ instead'.  In the meanwhile, I'm looking, but nothing leaps out at me.  Might want to echo the error instead of echp

Comment: ? is usually a palceholder in an sql statement for a prepared statement, could that be messing it up?

Comment: @Vasiliy - what's the database stucture? How large is the `text` field?

Comment: As of now I removed the m_r_e_s from the query - still no help. However I managed to catch an error with some tricks: Query parts != Params parts: q:0; p:1

Comment: An idea about placeholder messup is most probably right, as if I remove the "?" mark in my request - everything works fine. Thanks @Jeff Hawthorne But what to do about it? I still need the "?" mark in my link...

Comment: An obvious solution is to store data in base64_encode and do the base64_decode before sending. But this one is quite a problem as it requires to encode all current data in the table, update the sending script and so on. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I used the placeholder instead of $text and it made the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the **"?"** sign in the **$text** variable. It is being treated as a **placeholder** when it is put into the query, and the $db->query expects an array of variables. 
The solution is to use a **placeholder** instead of a **$text** variable and submit **$text** variable as params:

```
$ar[0]=$text;
$q = "INSERT INTO `messages` (`recepient`,`text`,`date`,`through`,`status`)";
$q.= " VALUES('".$to."',?,'".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."','".$through."',".$status.")";
$db->query($q,$ar);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `PDO`'s powerful **prepared statements**:

```
$q  = "INSERT INTO messages (recepient,text,date,through,status) ";
$q .= "VALUES (:to,:text,:date,:through,:status)";

$dbinsert = $db->prepare($q);
$dbinsert->execute(array(
    ':to' => $recipient,
    ':text' => $text,
    ':date' => $date,
    ':through' => $through,
    ':status' => $status));
```

This should do it.
Let PDO take care of escaping.

Comment: The query didn't work for me in neither case with short text or link in `text`

Comment: Looks like this is the solution to the problem, but I can't get it to work, It halts on `$db->prepare`

Comment: @Vasily of course, you need to set up PDO to connect to your database. Did you do that?

Comment: The thing is I'm working on a system that is not written by myself.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're mixing database libraries, or have wrapped things yourself.

If you're using something like mysqli or PDO for the `->query()` call, then `mysql_real_escape_string()` will **NOT** work. m_r_e_s() requires an active connection to the DB to operate. Connections established in mysql, mysqli, and PDO are **NOT** shareable between the libraries.

That means your m_r_e_s() calls will returning a boolean FALSE for failure, and your query will actually look like:

```
$q = "INSERT .... VAALUES ('', '', '', etc...)";
```

Comment: Will it return false only for the text containing the link? As it works perfecty with text like "test text".

Comment: I removed the m_r_e_s requests, but still no help. However I managed to catch an error: Query parts != Params parts: q:0; p:1

Answer (score 0):

What's the size of the `text` column in the database? It's mostly not the reason but I've noticed that your `$text` is **190** char long.

Comment: There is no length limitation on the `text` column. Moreover first thing I tried is adding the data through phpmyadmin SQL query and it worked fine.

Comment: Oh I wasn't sure you set its type to text, sorry for that